# ReactJs - Add a component when click button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, onchange

I have a dilemma that I can't find a solution to. I want to import many products while they may have the same category so when I click "+", the display will add a similar row like a picture [image]
I have seen many tutorials on the internet and followed them but they all failed. I don't know how to do this. Please help me! Thank you very much

```
state = {
  listItems: [],
  userInput: this.need,
}

need = {
  category: "",
  name: "",
  quantity: ""
}
    handleChange = (event) => {
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.value;
        const name = target.name;
        let userInput = { ...this.state.userInput };
        userInput[name] = value;
        this.setState({ userInput });
    }
    submitHandler = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        this.setState({
            listItems: [...this.state.listItems, this.state.userInput],
        })
    }
<Form>
<Form.Group id="need">
    <Row>
     <Col md="3">
       <label>Category</label>
       <select name="category" className="form-control" onChange={this.handleChange}>
         <option value="1">Water</option>
         <option value="2">Food</option>
       </select>
    </Col>
    <Col md="4">
      <label>Name</label>
        <Input
           name="name"
           className="form-control-alternative"
           onChange={this.handleChange}
           type="text"
         />
    </Col>
    <Col md="4">
      <label>Quantity</label>
      <Input
        name="quantity"
        className="form-control-alternative"
        type="text"
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
   </Col>
   <Col>
<i style={{ marginTop: 45 }} onClick={submitHandler} >Add more</i>
   </Col>
</Row>
</Form.Group>
</Form>
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-voice-0qdbu?file=/src/App.js)!

Comment: I didn't get it. I check your sandbox. And, I filled the fields and clicked Add More, nothing happened. What is the desired behavior?

Comment: In the display, I have a form with 3 tags: option, 2 input (I call it is a form1). When I click Add more, I want to display one more form1 on the below. In the picture I upload, when load page,  only have a row but when I click +/Add more it will display a similar row so I have 2 rows. I want to ask everyone how can I do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this kind of form, I prefer using [formik](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formik) to `this.setState`.

**Solution 1.** `this.setState`

I would design the state as follow

```js
this.state = {
  form: [
    {
      category: "",
      name: "",
      quantity: 0,
    },
  ],
};
```

and methods for adding more items, edit their content

```
handleAdd = () => {
  this.setState({
    form: [
      ...this.state.form,
      {
        category: "",
        name: "",
        quantity: 0,
      },
    ]
  });
};

handleEditFieldOfItem = (event, itemIndex, fieldName) => {
  const value = event.target.value;
  this.setState({
    form: this.state.form.map((item, index) => {
      if (index === itemIndex) {
        return { ...item, [fieldName]: value };
      }
      return item;
    })
  });
};
```

and I would render those items as follow:

```js
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.form.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index}>
            <div>
              <select value={item.category} onChange={(event) => { this.handleEditFieldOfItem(event, index, 'category'); }}>
                <option value="water">Water</option>
                <option value="food">Food</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div>
              <input type="text" value={item.name} onChange={(event) => { this.handleEditFieldOfItem(event, index, 'name'); }} />
            </div>
            <div>
              <input type="text" value={item.quantity} onChange={(event) => { this.handleEditFieldOfItem(event, index, 'quantity'); }} />
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
      <button onClick={this.handleAdd}>Add</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Solution 2.** Using Formik (with `FieldArray` component)

`Formik` comes with the abilities to validate, handle nested values, ...

You should check out [Formik documentation](https://formik.org/docs/overview) first.

```
import { Formik, Field, FieldArray } from "formik";

// ...

<Formik
  initialValues={{
    form: [
      {
        category: "",
        name: "",
        quantity: 0
      }
    ]
  }}
  onSubmit={(values, helpers) => {
    // 
  }}
>
  {(formikProps) => {
    const { values, handleSubmit } = formikProps;
    return (
      <>
        <FieldArray name="form">
          {(arrayHelpers) => {
            return (
              <div>
                {values.form.map((item, index) => {
                  return (
                    <div key={index}>
                      <Field as="select" name={`form.${index}.category`}>
                        <option value="water">Water</option>
                        <option value="food">Food</option>
                      </Field>
                      <Field name={`form.${index}.name`} />
                      <Field name={`form.${index}.quantity`} />
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
                <div>
                  <button onClick={() => arrayHelpers.push({ category: '', name: '', quantity: 0 })}>Add</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            )}}
        </FieldArray>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </>
    );
  }}
</Formik>
```

Comment: Cảm ơn bạn nhiều. Mình cũng biết Formik nhưng chỉ sử dụng ở mức cơ bản nhờ bạn mà mình biết thêm cách dùng Formik